# React Native createStackNavigator error.......(0, _reactnavigation.createStackNavigator) is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am getting the error "(0, _reactnavigation.createStackNavigator)" when trying to run a simple stackNavigator.....could someone please help?

the error is occurring at the line const AppStackNavigator = ***createStackNavigator***(....its showing a value of zero

```
 1. simple login screen

        import { View, Text, Card, Button } from 'react-native';
        import React from 'react';

        class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
          render() {
            return (
              <View>
                <Text>Hello Login</Text>
              </View>
            );
          }
        }
        export default LoginScreen;

2. App.js

    import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

    class App extends React.Component {
      render() {
            return (
          <View>
            <AppStackNavigator />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
      Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
    });

       export default App;

3. package.json

"react": "16.3.1",
"react-native": "^0.55.4",
"react-navigation": "^2.5.5",
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to import the `LoginScreen` to the `App.js`file. Hope it helps, cheers.